# Indentation inside tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, indentation, tcolorbox, xparse

I have a environment `solution` created with `xparse` and `tcolorbox`. I do not understand why package `\usepackage{indentfirst}` does not work inside `solution`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\Solution{Solution}
\usepackage[most, breakable, many]{tcolorbox}
\NewTColorBox[auto counter,number within=section]{solution}{+O{}}{%
    breakable, enhanced,colframe=gray,colback=white,coltitle=green!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
            \draw[help lines,step=5mm,blue!20!white,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
        title={\Solution},
        label={},
        attach title to upper=\quad,
        after upper={\par\hfill\textcolor{green!40!black}%
            {}},
        lowerbox=ignored,
        #1,
    }
\begin{document}
    \chapter{One}
       \begin{solution}
             \lipsum[1-35]
      \end{solution}
\end{document}
```

Comment: as your image shows parindent is zero inside the box, so there is effectively no indentation for any paragraph, so it's hard to know what you expect `indentfirst` to do???

Comment: @David Carlisleshows "parindent is zero inside the box" In what line of code you see it?

Comment: I didn't look too hard at the code, but the output shows several paragraphs with no indentation (which is the default for `\parbox` so not that surprising.

Comment: @ David Carlisle "which is the default for \parbox" Ok, now it is clear for me, I should to use parbox=false . Tnx, You  helped me again.

Comment: did I:-) If it's solved perhaps you should post a self-answer:-)

Comment: @sergiokapone `indentfirst` just makes LaTeX indent the first paragraph after a section title, which it doesn't by default as is customary in US typography. It has no effect in other situations.

Comment: @sergiokapone Do you want to make a self answer? If not, please leave a ping for david, so he can answer.

Comment: @Johannes_B I make a self answer.

Answer (score 7):

For paragraph indentation inside `tcolorbox` it is necesary to switch off the options `parbox`, e.g. `parbox=false` (by default it is `true`). Thus:

```
\NewTColorBox[auto counter,number within=section]{solution}{+O{}}{%
breakable, 
enhanced,
colframe=gray,
colback=white,
coltitle=green!40!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
parbox = false,
underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
\draw[help lines,step=5mm,blue!20!white,shift={(interior.north west)}]
                (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
          \end{tcbclipinterior}},
title={\Solution},
label={},
attach title to upper=\quad,
after upper={\par\hfill\textcolor{green!40!black}%
            {}},
lowerbox=ignored,
#1,
}
```

Comment: Easier for other user to see the solution that way ;-)